# Go program exits before goroutine workers complete

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm having an issue understanding how to properly block and close channels. I'm starting some arbitrary number of workers and I've discovered that my main function either exits before the workers have completed or hangs due to unclosed channel. I need a better way of blocking while the workers read the channel without main exiting and then gracefully close the channel to end the loop when it's done. Any attempt I've made ends in a deadlock.

I've tried a few things including using a wait group but the issue persists. I noticed that by adding `time.Sleep`, the program works as expected, but commenting it out results in no work done.

```golang
time.Sleep(time.Duration(10 * time.Second))
```

Here's a runable example https://go.dev/play/p/QHqNj-AJQBI with `Sleep` left in. And here's the broken code with the Sleep timeout commented out.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// some complicated work
func do(num int, ch chan<- int) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(500 * time.Millisecond))
    ch <- num
}

func main() {

    results := make(chan int)

    // for some number of required complicated work
    for i := 0; i < 53; i++ {
        go do(i, results)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // start 3 workers which can process results
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(id int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            worker(id, results)
        }(i)
    }

    // handle closing the channel when all workers complete
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()

    //time.Sleep(time.Duration(10 * time.Second))

    fmt.Println("donezo")
}

// process the results of do() in a meaningful way
func worker(id int, ch <-chan int) {
    fmt.Println("starting worker", id)

    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Println("channel val:", i)
    }
}
```

I've also tried moving the `defer wg.Done()` to inside the `worker()` func but it's the same issue and doesn't work without sleep.

```golang
// process the results of do() in a meaningful way
func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, id int, ch <-chan int) {
    fmt.Println("starting worker", id)

    defer wg.Done()

    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Println("channel val:", i)
    }
}
```

Have I chosen the wrong paradigm or am I just using it wrong?

Comment: You're using it wrong. You should call `wg.Wait` in `main` rather than in a goroutine; calling it in a goroutine means that `main` will not wait, and when `main` returns, the program exits.

Comment: Seems obvious now that you say it since that's where the sleep is. In the real code what "main" is above is actually in another function adding wg.Wait() followed by close(results) to the function body hangs, it waits and works like sleep but never hits the close() after it but the workers have all exited as far as I can tell. In the example above it panics with a goroutine deadlock so hard to test from the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally asked “*Is there a small tweak I can make to my code to make this work or do I have to rethink the problem?*” The answer I’ve discovered is, yes, there is a small tweak.

I had to learn an interesting fundamental concept about channels: You can read from a closed channel i.e. drain a channel. As mentioned the `range` in my original example never terminates because I couldn’t find a good place to close the channel and even when I forced it some other creative way the program was exhibiting undesired behaviour

- exiting short of processing all the contents within a channel
- deadlocks or send on closed channel

This is because of the nuances of the “*real*” code where processing the contents of a channel takes ***longer*** than it took to fill the channel and things were just out of sync.

Since there’s no clear practical way within my sender to close the channel which is recommended in 99% of channel tutorials, it’s actually acceptable to do it in main via a goroutine when you have multiple workers reading a channel and the workers are unaware of which of them read the last value.

### solution

I’ve wrapped the workers in their own `sync.WaitGroup` and used `worker.Wait()` to ***block*** the progam from exiting, allowing the works to “finish”. Independently I `close()` the channel when there's no more data to send, i.e. I block by waiting for the writers to finish by using their own wait group. The close gives the range loop a terminating case as it’ll end when the default value of the channel is returned, i.e. and EOF type return when the channel end is reached. A blocking rendezvous channel has no end, until it's closed.

The way I think about this is go has no way of knowing the length of an unbuffered channel as it’s being ranged over if you don’t know how many values will be pushed to it in parrellel, *until you close it*. Since closing it says read whatever is left until the terminating value or end. And the `workers.Wait()` blocks until that's complete.

example of the solved op
https://go.dev/play/p/NzKIYOqaGGD

example of reading a closed channel
https://go.dev/play/p/HYZofbz0Xc5

output

```
filling 0
filling 1
filling 2
filling 3
filling 4
filling 5
filling 6
filling 7
filling 8
filling 9
closed
empyting 0
empyting 1
empyting 2
empyting 3
empyting 4
empyting 5
empyting 6
empyting 7
empyting 8
empyting 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
// Start the workers first. This allows you to feed
// work to the workers without using goroutines.

var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(id int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        worker(id, results)
    }(i)
}

// Feed work to the workers.

for i := 0; i < 53; i++ {
    do(i, results)
}

// Close channel to indicate no more work. 
// This must come after all work is fed in.

close(results)

// Wait for workers to complete.
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: This bottlenecks the work producers `do(i, results)`. To keep the OP's design of concurrent requests: once all items have been written to the worker channel (e.g. track via another waitgroup), via another goroutine, wait for this event, then close the channel.

Comment: Write times and read times of the actual work done are not predictable. Your example won't work. When you range over a channel the loop doesn't break until `close` is called. You're essentially killing the loop before waiting for all values to be read out of the channel you might get 90% of them but you won't get all of them. Essentiall the program will only run as long as `do` runs and at larger volumes of work for the worker it doesn't ensure that the workers are finished, it cuts them off.